# Monthly View in Gantt-Chart

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint-2010

I have created a Daily Gantt-chart but am in need of monthly basis can anyone please give me the link or provide me the solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/r6emu/

```
 xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
},

yAxis: {
    tickInterval: 1,
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            if (tasks[this.value]) {
                return tasks[this.value].name;
            }
        }
    },
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false,
    title: {
        text: 'Activity'
    },
        minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kannankeril/fdTEx/5347/

```
minorTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,  // = 1 day
    type: 'datetime',
    min: Date.UTC(2012, 0, 3),
```

Comment: What do you expect a monthly view to show ? Your tasks are all much less than 1 month long.